# WhatsApp websocket

Tags: c#, криптография

пытаюсь установить соединение с WhatsApp Web по websocket, но не могу расшифровать Binnary Massage которые шифруются с помощи Curve25519.
Не могу найти приватный и публичный ключи для расшифровки, знаю что они приходят при подключении